# Django view works in "shell", but not when imported into existing view

Tags: python, django

Goal:  Display a countdown "clock" immediately after a page is loaded. (FWIW, it's intended to generate a visually loud and clear reminder of an impending deadline)

Platform: Windows

**countdown.py**:

```
import datetime, os, time
from Tkinter import *
from sys import exit


root = Tk()
time = ""
clock = Label(root, font=('times', 48, 'bold'), bg="cyan")
clock.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)


def getTime():
  -  finish = datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 4, 14, 45, 14, 281000)
  -  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  -  diff = finish - now
  -  minutes, seconds = divmod(diff.seconds, 60)
  -  hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
  -  string = "%d days %d hours %d minutes %d seconds" %    (diff.days,hours,minutes,seconds)
  - clock.config(text=string)
  - clock.after(200, getTime)

getTime()
root.mainloop()
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
-    url(r'^$', 'views.upn', name='site-homepage'),
-    (r'^ASSETS/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
-       {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
-    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
-    (r'^upn/$', 'views.upn'),
)
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
import urllib2
import countdown

def upn(request):
-return render_to_response("main.html")
```

**main.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<title>Main Page</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ASSETS/CSS/UPN.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<div class="maintext">
<div>


        <img class="MAINimg1" height="400" width="323" src="http://12345.jpg" border="0">

        <img class="MAINimg2" height="350" width="550" src="http://6789.jpg" border="0" border="0" >

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

If I run **"python manage.py shell"** at a windows command prompt, then **"import countdown.py"**, I get the desired result.

However, if I incorporate it into the *views.py* and **"import countdown"**, I get the following (traceback):

**Traceback:**

```
File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  83.                     request.path_info)

    File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve

  218.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve

  125.             return self.callback, args, kwargs

File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback

  137.             raise ViewDoesNotExist, "Tried %s in module %s. Error was: %s" % 
(func_name, mod_name, str(e))


Exception Type: ViewDoesNotExist at /

Exception Value: Tried upn in module views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'argv'
```

The error:

***File "D:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  137.             raise ViewDoesNotExist, "Tried %s in module %s. Error was: %s" % (func_name, mod_name, str(e)) ***

seems to be the key, but I cannot interpret this error accurately enough to make the necessary corrections.

Thanks in advance for any intel you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with your urlconf, it could not find the entire view.

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out `root.mainloop()` from your code, the error will go away but this is not going to solve your problem of showing a window on the desktop.

To do that, you need to have a program on the desktop (perhaps the same program `countdown.py`) listen for a signal from your web service and then launch the timer.

If you ***must*** initiate this code on a request, you will need to do it somewhere in the wsgi handler of your application, where the traditional argc/argv are present; however I **strongly** advise against this and recommend the listener/query approach.